# Why request is empty but "content:protected" not?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm sending parameters (interseccion, calle, numero) through the PUT method and JSON format.
I want to receive in php (Symfony2) with `$this->request->request` but when I do a var_dump there is no parameter.
However, the parameter are but in the `"content": protected.` tag

I am sending the dump of `$this->request` and `$this->request->request`

[image]

In the case, how I can retrive the parameters (interseccion, calle, numero) from the `"content": protected.` tag ?

> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)#6 (20) {
>   ["attributes"]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#9 (1) {
>   ["parameters":protected]=> array(8) { ["_controller"]=> string(60)
>   "MiCiudad\MgpBundle\Controller\MgpController::solicitudAction"
>   ["_route"]=> string(26) "miciudad_mgp_mgp_solicitud"
>   ["_route_params"]=> array(0) { } ["_template"]=> string(15)
>   "index.html.twig" ["_method"]=>
>   object(Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method)#412
>   (1) { ["methods":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "PUT" } }
>   ["_template_vars"]=> array(0) { } ["_template_streamable"]=>
>   bool(false) ["_template_default_vars"]=> array(0) { } } }
>   **["request"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#7 (1) {
>   ["parameters":protected]=> array(0) { } }** ["query"]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#8 (1) {
>   ["parameters":protected]=> array(2) { ["apiKey"]=> string(8)
>   "MiCiudad" ["hash"]=> string(32) "e8e9beb0f0a2dd4800929566d13d2ce2" }
>   } ["server"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag)#12
>   (1) { ["parameters":protected]=> array(44) { ["MIBDIRS"]=> string(24)
>   "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs" ["MYSQL_HOME"]=> string(16)
>   "\xampp\mysql\bin" ["OPENSSL_CONF"]=> string(31)
>   "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf" ["PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]=>
>   string(10) "\xampp\php" ["PHPRC"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["TMP"]=>
>   string(10) "\xampp\tmp" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(14) "miciudad.local"
>   ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=>
>   string(4) "1238" ["HTTP_ORIGIN"]=> string(51)
>   "chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo"
>   ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(108) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76
>   Safari/537.36" ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=> string(16) "application/json"
>   ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(3) "*/*" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
>   string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(15)
>   "es-419,es;q=0.8" ["PATH"]=> string(397)
>   "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;%SSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\xampp\php\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\bin;C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin;;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;" ["SystemRoot"]=> string(10) "C:\Windows" ["COMSPEC"]=>
>   string(27) "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" ["PATHEXT"]=> string(53)
>   ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC" ["WINDIR"]=>
>   string(10) "C:\Windows" ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(98) "
>       Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 Server at miciudad.local Port 80
>       " ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(45) "Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(14)
>   "miciudad.local" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1"
>   ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(9)
>   "127.0.0.1" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(32)
>   "C:/xampp/htdocs/miCiudad-Web/web" ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=> string(4)
>   "http" ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=> string(0) "" ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
>   string(32) "C:/xampp/htdocs/miCiudad-Web/web" ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
>   string(19) "admin@localhost.com" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(44)
>   "C:/xampp/htdocs/miCiudad-Web/web/app_dev.php" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
>   string(5) "50953" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1"
>   ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
>   string(3) "PUT" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(53)
>   "apiKey=MiCiudad&hash=e8e9beb0f0a2dd4800929566d13d2ce2"
>   ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(80)
>   "/app_dev.php/mgp/solicitud?apiKey=MiCiudad&hash=e8e9beb0f0a2dd4800929566d13d2ce2"
>   ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(12) "/app_dev.php" ["PATH_INFO"]=> string(14)
>   "/mgp/solicitud" ["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=> string(27)
>   "redirect:\app.php\solicitud" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(26)
>   "/app_dev.php/mgp/solicitud" ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
>   float(1380716540.164) ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1380716540) } }
>   ["files"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)#11 (1) {
>   ["parameters":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["cookies"]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#10 (1) {
>   ["parameters":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["headers"]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag)#13 (2) {
>   ["headers":protected]=> array(10) { ["host"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(14) "miciudad.local" } ["connection"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(10) "keep-alive" } ["content-length"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(4) "1238" } ["origin"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(51)
>   "chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo" }
>   ["user-agent"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(108) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36" } ["content-type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16)
>   "application/json" } ["accept"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "*/*" }
>   ["accept-encoding"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch"
>   } ["accept-language"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "es-419,es;q=0.8"
>   } ["x-php-ob-level"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } }
>   ["cacheControl":protected]=> array(0) { } } **["content":protected]=>
>   string(1238) "{"interseccion"="LA RIOJA","calleCorregida":"LA
>   RIOJA","numeroCorregido":"3800","direccionValidada":1,"tipoSolicitudId":"8","datos_extendidos":{},"idioma":"es","descripcion":"","datos_personales":{"telefono":"0201AB1FAFC5E521C3AD003D7BBBE809D13EFBB5936BF2F11B471160699ADA15FF34B0CBD8D6281E5CC04D8DF9270E21EA831D571EF4C198FA6FC85D50E7D75FE2CC8E6F00FDFBFE58A594369C33BBB5261C","apellido":"020129C5BEA971F8980B95F4058485EDEC79C3DC5D2393DBBB5D18857EF1685363839B81B5F5B0BADFCCD2E31E254F9270FC5DE7D81917FABD985222014DFA87FE495E23A3964B215976749B4811C9464EB1","nombre":"0201BFF9E505FCF6DD4E0697EE1B888D4862740A6AFBFEDF0AC0ED98E733245EE8B926EF2FEBCD7D0DD94818FDDDE7C13347BED4E5ED93D5D6DFF98A18D93A2C77808B2CE58EB8CE8FB45651B9CE77E2F89B","email":"020163DCA47AF4EF8A3A654BBBE80C9678A8757B908CCECBBCFEE1445977B21A534391F7B392BA14B7FCC026FFFB384A14DAB65FB6E09B14183B8E9D379666D9964B01C42BC2E10425007DD8C7209EF34CB2E5873082522BDCDED2955B800BCCB2E3","dni":"0201635402DDF67E1EBCAE620B2EE713719B687904BA111462FA998424E78BA310C0D8ED04071118215B47B25BA1D9C730398C16F62BB888C7F26591BC3D2E518D24CF325F41CD0386D9B172241DC4500CDD"},"calleId":"00691","latitud":"-38.0149720701376","dispositivoId":"476","longitud":"-57.565044058572","foto":"","calle":"FORMOSA"}"**
>   ["languages":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "es_419" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea2MF.png)=>
>   string(2) "es" } ["charsets":protected]=> NULL
>   ["acceptableContentTypes":protected]=> NULL ["pathInfo":protected]=>
>   string(14) "/mgp/solicitud" ["requestUri":protected]=> string(80)
>   "/app_dev.php/mgp/solicitud?apiKey=MiCiudad&hash=e8e9beb0f0a2dd4800929566d13d2ce2"
>   ["baseUrl":protected]=> string(12) "/app_dev.php"
>   ["basePath":protected]=> NULL ["method":protected]=> string(3) "PUT"
>   ["format":protected]=> string(4) "html" ["session":protected]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session)#99 (3) {
>   ["storage":protected]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage)#98
>   (5) { ["bags":protected]=> array(2) { ["attributes"]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag)#94
>   (3) {
>   ["name":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag":private]=>
>   string(10) "attributes"
>   ["storageKey":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag":private]=>
>   string(15) "_sf2_attributes" ["attributes":protected]=> array(0) { } }
>   ["flashes"]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag)#93 (3)
>   {
>   ["name":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag":private]=>
>   string(7) "flashes"
>   ["flashes":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag":private]=>
>   array(0) { }
>   ["storageKey":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag":private]=>
>   string(12) "_sf2_flashes" } } ["started":protected]=> bool(false)
>   ["closed":protected]=> bool(false) ["saveHandler":protected]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy)#95
>   (4) { ["handler":protected]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler)#97
>   (0) { } ["wrapper":protected]=> bool(true) ["active":protected]=>
>   bool(false) ["saveHandlerName":protected]=> string(5) "files" }
>   ["metadataBag":protected]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag)#96
>   (4) {
>   ["name":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag":private]=>
>   string(10) "__metadata"
>   ["storageKey":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag":private]=>
>   string(9) "_sf2_meta" ["meta":protected]=> array(3) { ["c"]=> int(0)
>   ["u"]=> int(0) ["l"]=> int(0) }
>   ["lastUsed":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag":private]=>
>   NULL } }
>   ["flashName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session":private]=>
>   string(7) "flashes"
>   ["attributeName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session":private]=>
>   string(10) "attributes" } ["locale":protected]=> string(6) "es_419"
>   ["defaultLocale":protected]=> string(2) "es" }

`$this->request->request`

> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#7 (1) {
>   ["parameters":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting JSON objects to Symfony 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522029/posting-json-objects-to-symfony-2)

Comment: Not working! 

$params = array();
$content = $this->request->getContent();
if (!empty($content))
{
    $params = json_decode($content, true); 
}
var_dump($params);

object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#7 (1) { ["parameters":protected]=> array(0) { } } NULL

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference or not but your JSON is invalid:  `{"interseccion"="LA RIOJA","calleCorregida":"LA RIOJA","numeroCorregido":"3800","direccionValidada":1,...` should be `{"interseccion":"LA RIOJA","calleCorregida":"LA RIOJA","numeroCorregido":"3800","direccionValidada":1,...` the equals sign (=) is not a valid JSON assignment character so your `json_decode` may not be working.

Comment: Could you provide a smaller example? maybe just the controller and the request made to reproduce it.