# Symfony2.6 Empty Post data with rest service

Tags: rest, symfony, post

When sending a request from Poster (firefox addon) in post to production server, this is not able to collect the variables sent in json, because the post is empty.I have also tried to send variables through application / x-www-form-urlencoded, but post to remains empty.

I use paramfetcher of restbundle, but post is empty.

I use :

file_get_contents("php://input");

But the value is array(0){}.

Can anyone help?
Please ..... I will explode the brain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522029/posting-json-objects-to-symfony-2 not working?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not the json deserialization. The problem is that I receive post empty and there is nothing to deserialize. I have already spoken to the media server to see if there is anything that may be blocking the post requests, but nothing.