# PHP - How to get POSTFIELDS sent with CURL?

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I am using curl to call API method (Symfony2, FOSRestBundle) and wonder how can I get the data sent in POSTFIELDS?

```
    $_params = [];
    $data_string = json_encode($_params);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $_method);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    $json = curl_exec($curl);
```

If I send something in for example `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` I can get it later in controller using

```
$request->headers->get("some_variable");
```

But how can I access `$data_string`? I have dumped almost every possible variable and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a `POST` value in `symphony` you can use:

```
$request->request->get('key', 'default value');
```

---

Assuming `$_params` is a valid `json` object, you need to `url-ify` the data for the `POST`, i.e.:

```
$post_fields = http_build_query(json_decode($_params));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); </s>
```

---

To retrieve  `all` post values in `symphony` you can use:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
$params['val1'];
$params['val2'];
```

Comment: That's correct, but i need to get all POST variables send with CURL.
I mean i need to retrevie value of variable $data_string.

Comment: I have updated my question a little bit. My problem is that i need to access $data_string variable in a controller, when $_params is an array (sometimes empty, sometimes contains some keys and values)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your first code snippet, you're effectively trying to POST a JSON string? It was my understanding that your PHP code wouldn't work as per the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value.

But as per [this blog post](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl) apparently you can do it your way.

Anyway, back to your question. To get the full content of a request, you would do:

```
$content = $request->getContent();
```

And to then decode the JSON you would do:

```
$params = json_decode($content);
```

[Another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565770/4545769) covers this. About the only thing I'd say is that you need to correctly set the MIME type when you're sending the post, e.g.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json' ]);
```

The previously mentioned blog post covers this.

Comment: You saved my day with this code :) Thank you :)

$content = $request->getContent();