# How can I get post parameters on ajax request in Symfony 3

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I have an ajax request working fine. My problem is I do not really know how to use correctly my controller to get the datas in the format I would like.

I would like to use this kind of method:

```
$request->request->get('pseudo'); // will return "bob"
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function mainPlayAction(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $allContent = $request->getContent(); // will return a string with this format "selectedBalls=34&selectedStars=11"

        $selectedBalls = $request->request->get('selectedBalls'); // will return null

        $selectedstars= $request->request->get('selectedStars'); // will return null

        $all = $request->request->all(); // will return Array[0]

        $response = [
            'allContent' => $allContent,
            'selectedballs' => $selectedBalls,
            'selectedStars' => $selectedStars,
            'all' => $all,                
            'success' => true,
            "status" => 100
        ];

        return $this->json($response);
    }
}
```

Here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'selectedballs': selectedBalls,
        'selectedStars': selectedStars,
        'countGames': countGames
    },
    success: function (response) {
        window.console.log(response);
    },
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522029/posting-json-objects-to-symfony-2

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to call `->get()` on `Request` object to get the data passwed along with AJAX Request.

**Like this,**

```
$selectedballs=$request->get('selectedballs');
$selectedStars=$request->get('selectedStars');
$countGames=$request->get('countGames');
```

Comment: Trying to implement your solution but is does not seem to work. I'm sure your answer is the good one but I'm looking for what is wrong in my code

Comment: Actually, this won't work at all for posted json data.

Comment: @Cerad can you tell me what I have to do ?

Comment: @Cerad OP is passing the data as parameters and not as JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer.

I deleted this line of code from my ajax request

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

And now I can retrieve my datas using

```
$request->get('selectedBalls');
```

Comment: When you get a chance, read up a bit on the difference between posting json and posting form data.  Your solution is not sustainable.

Comment: I mad a mistake in my solution and I edited it. Now i use $request->get('selectedBalls') . According to you isn't it a good solution ? Note: I send ajax datas without using any form.

Comment: Read the answer in the link I gave you.  In particular, look at how $content is used.

Comment: Sorry. I have tried since 30 min to implement the solution of the link you posted. But I'm not able to implement it. 

Using the function $request->getcontent() returns me a string "url encoded" like "id=34&pseudo=bob" . . . and then sure ... json_decode function doesn't works on that string format.