# Send ajax data to php controller in symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

Hi guys I am new in symfony 2 and i have little confusing with sending data with ajax to php controller in symfony 2. I want to create project with google map so i create MapController:

```
   <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
class MapController extends Controller
{ 
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('map/map.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
            'contData' => ['lat' => '51.24591334500776', 'lng'=> '22.56967306137085']
        ]);
    }


    public function saveAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->request->get('params');

         return new JsonResponse(['data' => $data], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

}
```

then i create routing:

```
    app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
map:
    path:      /map
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Map:index }
    requirements:
        page: '\d+' 
map_save:
    path:      /map/save
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Map:save }
    methods:  [POST]
```

so when i go to to route:

> http://localhost/googlemap/web/app_dev.php/map

i display my template map.html.twig

there i have javascipt function where i tried to send ajax data to some controller:

```
    marker.addListener("click", function () {


                    //!
                    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var url = "map/save";
                    var params = marker.position.lat();
                    http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
                    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    http.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
                        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                            alert(http.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                    http.send(params);
```

But i have NULL in this response:
{"data":null}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask yourself what do you want to do with this data sent from JS. If it's related to map feature then creating a new method in MapController seems fine. If it's not related to maps then creating a new controller could be a good way to go.

Naming of method and controller should be relevant to what you're doing. Your `saveData` example is not so obvious. If you're saving coordinates then you could name this method `saveCoordinatesAction` and define a dedicated route supporting POST requests only.

As for passing the URL to JS, check out [FOSJsRoutingBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) - it lets you generate specific routes directly from JavaScript.

Comment: i know but this function name is only for test now. So when I create a method saveCoordinatesAction in my MapController, then how should look my var url in javascript? I tried to used "map/saveCoordinatesAction ", "map/saveCoordinates", ""app_dev.php/map/saveCoordinatesAction ", and other combinations but this request stil not reaches, not come to my php function in this controller

Comment: mam POST http://localhost/googlemap/web/app_dev.php/saveCoordinatesAction 404 (Not Found), szczerze jestem nowy w symfony kilka godzin temu postawiłem projekt, żeby się nauczyć i te rutingi mnie jescze trochę mylą, wcześniej używałem np Yii2 framework, gdzie w ogole nie trzeba się martwić o takei sprawy

Comment: English will be easier for other people to join our discussion. 

If your base URL is `http://localhost/googlemap/web/app_dev.php/` then you should use all of this (including `http://` protocol prefix) in the URL which your javascript calls, e.g. `http://localhost/googlemap/web/app_dev.php/saveCoordinates` (`app_dev.php` is optional just don't leave it there on your production server) but you need to define a route for this address in `routing.yml` file just as you did for the `map` URL.

Comment: You can also check your `dev.log` file to see if this request made from JS hits your app. Also, use `php bin/console debug:router` CLI command to check if your `saveCoordinates` route is defined properly (meaning that it is listed on the output of that command).

Comment: ok now this function in PHP for test is naming saveAction(), then in route I have: `map_save:
    path:      /map/save
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Map:save }
    methods:  [POST]` and in js `var url = "map/save";`

Comment: and now my error look like  POST http://localhost/googlemap/web/app_dev.php/map/save 500 (Internal Server Error), The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? what this mean my post data is null?

Comment: It says that your controller must **return** a response. This means that you don't have a return statement in your controller method. Since your're invoking this address in JS, it probably will be useful to return a JSON so you could do it like this: `return new JsonResponse(['your' => 'response array'], Response::HTTP_OK)`

Comment: ok i think i understand this now I msut return new response now

Comment: ok but how can i got this data, I understand I should do something like `$data = $request->request->get('data');
         return new JsonResponse(['your' => $data], Response::HTTP_OK);` but how can I got this data now to save in database?

Comment: You should [validate it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) and [store it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) (using doctrine for example) by creating an [entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class) with all the mappings and stuff mentioned in the docs and finally you can [persist it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database).

Comment: Use json_decode($request->getContent(),true) to access the data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522029/posting-json-objects-to-symfony-2  In the future consider starting a new question for new questions.  Better yet, just search the board.

Comment: but i now got a null in this response can You try to help me in free time with this? I update all my first post like my current code in project

Comment: ok i used 
        $content = $request->getContent(); instead of $data = $request->request->get('params'); thank You guys for help :)) Have a nice day :))