# Symfony: Integrity constraint violation: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, json, symfony

I have a one to many relationship between two tables in a symmfony application. The registration method of one of the table accepts a JSON POST request. On attempting to insert data into the database manually from mysql interface everything is fine but when I attempt to use a POST request to perform the insertion I get

```
500 Internal Server Error with a Integrity constraint violation:
```

this is the controller of the POST request

```
                   $register->setConfirmpassword($params["confirmpassword"]);
                   $register->setAccountfk($params["accountsfk"]);
```

this is the sample JSON post from postman

```
{
    "accountsfk":2
    }
```

registration has a foreign key to accounts. On making a post request I get this error

with params ["myname", "mylastname", "emails123@email.com", "passwords", "passwords", null]:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;accountsfk&#039; cannot be null (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Please what am doing wrong that I am unable to insert records to the registration table

Comment: Can you please show your entity?

Comment: which of the entity

Comment: entity Registration please

Comment: accountsfk is a relation with Account?

Comment: yes from registration table I have accountsfk pointing to the id of Account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting JSON objects to Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522029/posting-json-objects-to-symfony-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that accountsfk is a foreign key so you need to pass the account not the id to the registration, something like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();       
$account = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Account')->find($params["accountsfk"]);

$register->setFirstname($params["firstname"]);
$register->setLastname($params["lastname"]);
$register->setEmail($params["email"]);
$register->setPassword($params["password"]);
$register->setConfirmpassword($params["confirmpassword"]);
$register->setAccountfk($params["accountsfk"]);
$register->setAccounts($account]);
```

In first line I get the account but I don't know which is your bundle and your entity for account, but It's important to understand that you have to pass an entity not the id into `setAccountfk`

You have setAccountfk that isn't necessary I think, you only need setAccounts to relation registration to account

Comment: read the log file if there is more information, try to var_dump $account to check if there is an account, after try to update question with registration entity

Comment: ok I have seen the dump and seems to be correct so I think that the entity Registration has a problem. could you post it into the question?

Comment: Update answer @parker

Comment: Thank u. This did the final trick >>>>>>
$register->setAccounts($account);

Comment: perfect! Glad to help you!