# No request parameters after post request with json

Tags: json, symfony, post, request

I've got problem: when I send post request to my symfony api, and I try to get $request->request, and dump it (using dd() helper), I get empty parameters array, and I have no idea why it happen.

I'm using Postman to test this api, and my example object looks like:

```
{
   "day": "2018-10-13T08:50:45.802Z",
   "songs": [
       {
           "title":"Song title",
           "songType": 5,
           "number": 237
       }
    ]
}
```

And result is:
[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRLTf.png)

Does anyone know how to get expected request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting JSON objects to Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522029/posting-json-objects-to-symfony-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Symfony's Request class asumes form data set via HTTP headers.

To fetch the json request body, do this: 
`$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);`

Comment: Thank you! I've just noticed that I confused json_encode with json_decode.